# How to serach for books in google api

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to display all the books from google api based on a passed value and then insert them into the database. I can't visualize how to pass value to the class responsible for getting response. Solution which currently I'm trying to use is dajngo forms. Below is a fragment of my code.

views:

```
class GoogleImportBook(FormView): 
    model = Book
    form_class = GoogleImportForm
    template_name = "API/search_for_book.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("books_api") 


    def book_search(self, value):
        param = {"q":value, "key":settings.API_KEY}
        api_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes"
        response = requests.get(url=api_url, params=param)
        items = response.json()["items"]
        for item in items:
            print(item["volumeInfo"]["title"])
```

forms.py

```
class GoogleImportForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields=["q"]
```

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    publication_date = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField("Author", related_name="author")
    ISBN = ISBNField() 
    pages = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_all_authors(self):
        return "".join([x.name +", " for x in self.authors.all()])[:-2]


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["title"]
```

I assume than using regular django forms is not a good practice for worki with REST in django.

Comment: Why exactly do you use a model here? It looks like you only need a `Form` (not a `ModelForm`) to make a search?

Comment: By mistake I was speeding up with creating a form just to pass value to the class. 
now it's switched to Form, but I'm still looking a for good way to pass there this parameter.

Comment: You have a `FormView` so it has a `form_valid()` method which is what gets called when the input is valid. Just call your `book_search()` method from your `form_valid()` method.